# import react-is as esm

Tags: reactjs, vite, rollup, rollupjs

I have multiple packages that use `hoist-non-react-statics`, which uses the following import

```js
import { ForwardRef, Memo, isMemo } from 'react-is';
```

This [react-is](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/main/packages/react-is) package doesn't export as `esm`, but uses `umd` and `commonjs` instead.

I am using `vitejs` as my dev server, which uses `rollup` to built the code. The dev server works fine, the built doesn't.

My build options are the following:

```js
commonjsOptions: {
  include: [
    "react-is",
    "hoist-non-react-statics/src/index.js"
  ],
  ignoreGlobal: true,
  transformMixedEsModules: true,
  ignore: ["global"],
  esmExternals: true,
  requireReturnsDefault: true
}
target: ["esNext"],
```

As I mentioned it doesn't work this way. The error is as follows:

```
file: /home/user/project/node_modules/hoist-non-react-statics/src/index.js:5:9
3:  * Copyrights licensed under the New BSD License. See the accompanying LICENSE file for terms.
4:  */
5: import { ForwardRef, Memo, isMemo } from 'react-is';
            ^
6: 
7: const REACT_STATICS = {
error during build:
Error: 'ForwardRef' is not exported by node_modules/hoist-non-react-statics/node_modules/react-is/index.js, imported by node_modules/hoist-non-react-statics/src/index.js
```

What can I do to make it work, if it's possible at all?

Comment: any chance you solved this? Im having the exact same issue

Comment: Just to chime in, we actually just ran into this issue as well. I had been guessing this was due to a React version mismatch between dependencies but after checking in node_modules I do see all of the exports here but the build process still throws an error.

Comment: I didn't solve this issue. Basically my solution is to not use this sort of thing anymore.